Error adding File Provider domain: No valid file provider found with identifier ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost’ on MacOS
Maybe smb has counted on a similar issue.
Getting No valid file provider found with identifier ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost’ on registering a file provider domain with NSFileProviderManager.add(domain)
MyApp structure (XCode project):

Host app

SwiftUI app with a hidden window

A target, host app to register file provider

Bundle identifier:  ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost’

App group: ‘group.MyApp’



Apple File Provider Finder extension

A target, extension plugin

Bundle identifier:  ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost.Extension’

App group: ‘group.MyApp’




The problem code (the host app ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost’):
import SwiftUI
import FileProvider

@main
struct MyApp_FinderExtensionHostApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
        // ...
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {

        let domainIdentifier = NSFileProviderDomainIdentifier(rawValue: "MyApp.FinderExtensionHost.Extension")
        let domain = NSFileProviderDomain(identifier: domainIdentifier, displayName: "MyApp")

        // Register the File Provider domain
        NSFileProviderManager.add(domain) { error in
            if let error = error {
                self.logger.error("Error adding File Provider domain: \(error.localizedDescription)") // <<-- We are here. And why "No valid file provider found with identifier ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost’", not ‘MyApp.FinderExtensionHost.Extension’??!
            } else {
                self.logger.info("File Provider domain added successfully!")
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}

The character of issue is accidental. I didn't find the exact reasons.
I've tried cache cleaning. Smt it works, smt not:
pkill -9 cloudd
pkill -9 bird
pkill -9 fileproviderd
killall Finder

This cmd doesn't show my domain in the list:
pluginkit -mvv -p com.apple.fileprovider-nonui


Yes, me!! And I posted the same question, still waiting for answer and I opened a bounty!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79061369/unable-to-find-file-provider-extension-with-identifier

@FrancescoPiraneoG. Hi! Have u tried UID as domain identifier?
let domain = NSFileProviderDomain(identifier: NSFileProviderDomainIdentifier(rawValue: NSUUID().uuidString), displayName: "Test")

This has happening with me as well. I found that when I restart Xcode (I'm on 16.1) and rebuild the app, it takes a while to perform "Gather Provisioning Inputs" and after that, I no longer get this error (for a while).
